# How can I make these 2 columns flush at the top?

Tags: android, android-layout

This layout is a background image, title, and 2 columns.  The first column is an image.  The second column is a Name and Subtitle.  Looking at the 2 columns, the left image is slightly above the text column.  Adding "layout_alignParentTop="true" to the LinearLayout text column didn't help.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/nature_backdrop"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/steel_grey"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/intro_title"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/first_row_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/flight"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_row_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/flight_info"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/flight_info_desc"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting gravity on the linear layout and the contents if necessary.  If you are targeting api level 17 and up you can set textAlignment="gravity".

I also blended your bg image into the linear layout. That may or may not work for you, but thought it might save you some code.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:background="@drawable/nature_backdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/steel_grey"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/intro_title"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_row_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flight"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_row_icon"
        android:gravity="top">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/flight_info"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/flight_info_desc"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: adding gravity="top" had no effect :(

Comment: try setting a different bright background colour on each of the cells to find out which one is adding the padding you do not want.